Authorize not working as expected in Blazor
I have a .NET 8 server-side Blazor app. It uses Entra ID for authentication and I've created a CustomAuthenticationStateProvider that gets roles from a database.
public class CustomAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    private readonly IDBAccess _roleService; // Custom service to fetch roles from the database
    private IMemoryCache _cache;

    public CustomAuthenticationStateProvider(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, IDBAccess roleService, IMemoryCache cache)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        _roleService = roleService;
        _cache = cache;
    }
    
    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        var user = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User;
        
        AuthenticationState retval = new AuthenticationState(user ?? new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity()));
        
        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
             _cache.TryGetValue("principal", out ClaimsPrincipal principal);
             
             var newUser = principal;

             if (principal == null)
             {
                 // Fetch additional roles from the database
                 var username = user.Identity.Name; // Get user's name
                 var dbuser = await _roleService.GetUserByName(username); 
                 
                 if (dbuser != null)
                 {
                     // Add the custom roles to a new ClaimsIdentity
                     var claims = new List<Claim>(user.Claims);
                     
                     claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, dbuser.Role));
                     
                     var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, user.Identity.AuthenticationType);
                     
                     newUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
                     
                     _cache.Set("principal", newUser);
                     
                     retval = new AuthenticationState(newUser);
                 }
             }
             else
             {
                 retval = new AuthenticationState(newUser);
             }
        }
        
        return retval;
    }
}

It seems to work fine, it fetches the roles from the db and adds it to the ClaimsPrincipal before returning it in the AuthenticationState.
As soon as I add @attribute [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")] to my page however, I get an "Access Denied" error. If I remove the Authorize attribute, and look for the role using IsInRole in the code, it finds it no problem.
What am I missing?
Additional...
I added a role in Azure and associated it with my user. if I debug the CustomAuthenticationStateProvider I can see it in the claims. It has the same ClaimType as the Role I am adding. If I change the role in my Authorise attribute to match the one from Azure, it works. Is it a timing or refresh thing? I've now added a NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(newUser))); line just after the newUser ClaimsPrincipal is added, but that makes no difference...

Could you pls share the tutorial you followed to work on your app? Blazor in .net 8 removed blazor server but added blazor web app, and in .net 8 blazor web app document, there's no tutorial for integrating Azure Entra Id yet. So that I'm afraid any unexpected behavior shall be expected....

Here's the link: https://www.faciletechnolab.com/blog/part-2-how-to-implement-microsoft-entra-id-authentication-in-blazor-server-web-app-in-net-8/ and you are right its a web app - I still think of it as server side as the render mode is set to InteractiveServer.

Thanks a lot, but that blog doesn't include created a CustomAuthenticationStateProvider that gets roles from a database, it only integrate Azure AD into your app, which could help your app to allow users to sign in with Microsoft account. It doesn't require a database.

No, that was added extra as I want roles for the app to be controlled in the separate db (the admin user needs to assign them to app users at his level and no way will he be given azure access). The skeleton for the Custom method was supplied via judicious use of ChatGPT...

Can I say, the users of your app use their microsoft account to sign in the app, and you have a database which stores the role-user mapping relationship. After users sign in, your app would query the database to get the role, and you want your blazor app to check whether this user has correct role to visit some pages, right? If so, we need to refer to blazor authorization mechanism, it provides us [Authorize] attribute and role/claim based authorization scheme, but it doesn't cover your scenario.

In my humble opinion. a custom auth state provider is helped to control authentication,but you already had AAD as authentication scheme which causing a conflict. And I think this is the reason for the issue. Maybe you can have a workaround to achieve it finally, but I think you can use AzureAD to do the role-management task and this might reduce much time.

I have implemented a workaround using the IsInRole method, which works but isn't as slick as using authorise. I think in the long term I'm going to look at the Azure API for adding roles that way.

I agree with you, and maybe Graph API could help.

I had a further investigation in my side, based on the custom auth provider document, we could see that when we want to change the user identity(such as add user role which is queried out from the database) we need to call NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged method, and it's only available in a custom auth provider. In your case, you followed that link to integrate Azure AD auth which isn't use a custom auth provider, so that I'm afraid that you can't achieve in that way...
